# Display results of a form

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to find a simple way to display the results of a simple checkbox form on the same page after submit. I know you can use the `drupal_set_message`, but I want to display the results formatted on the page, not in the message box.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message($this->t('Your favorite car is @fav_car', array('@fav_car' => $form_state->getValue('fav_car'))));
      }
    }
```

Full code for form here;

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\cars\Form\FavoriteCarForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\cars\Form:

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\cars\CarsStorage;

/**
 * Class FavoriteCarForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\cars\Form
 */
class FavoriteCarForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'favorite_car_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['fav_car'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => $this->t('What is your favorite Car!'),
      '#options' => array('Toyota' => $this->t('toyota'), 'Ford' => $this->t('Ford'), 'Subaru' => $this->t('Subaru')),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('Your favorite car is @fav_car', array('@fav_car' => $form_state->getValue('fav_car'))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not different from what is done in Drupal 7:

- When building the form, you verify in `$form_state` a value is present; if it is present you show its value
- In the submission form handler, you tell Drupal to rebuild it

What changes is the code you actually use, since Drupal 8 introduces new classes Drupal 7 doesn't have.

```
class FavoriteCarForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'favorite_car_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['fav_car'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => $this->t('What is your favorite Car!'),
      '#options' => array('Toyota' => $this->t('toyota'), 'Ford' => $this->t('Ford'), 'Subaru' => $this->t('Subaru')),
    );

    if ($form_state->getValue('fav_car')) {
      // Show the value the user entered.
    }

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
}
```

Calling `$form_state->setRebuild()` causes Drupal to call `buildForm()` again, passing in `$form_state` the values the user submitted and the values added from validation and submission handlers.

I didn't add the code to write the submitted value. You could:

- Show it as description of the form element
- Show it in a #markup element

I would rather not implement such code for just showing the selected value, though. I would use it to show the result of an elaboration done from the input given from users, for example showing a map of the town entered from users.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to display it on the same page as the form, then you can check the value in form state and put it in another render array, for example with the [`ProcessedText`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!filter!src!Element!ProcessedText.php/class/ProcessedText/8) class that extends [`RenderElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!RenderElement.php/class/RenderElement/8).

```php
if ($form_state->getValue('fav_car')) {
  $form['something'] = [
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $form_state->getValue('fav_car'),
    '#format' => filter_default_format()
  ];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't really understand.

Comment: @mradcliffe is suggesting that you add the information as another element of your form, as part of `FavoriteCarForm:: buildForm()`. Notice that $form_state gets passed to buildForm(). He/she's suggesting that if $form_state indicates that the fav_car value is not empty (there's a typo; you want getValue('fav_car')), then add a form element that shows the value.

Comment: For whatever reason the font I had at home was not showing the underscores so I thought there was literally a space in the element key. Thank you for the clarification @TorenwareNetworks.